# Xamarin forms: Statusbar doesn't update color when NavBar changes color on Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm making an app with Xamarin Forms.
Usually the app will have a blue NavBar, but I'm changing the NavBarfor a specific page.

The way I do that is:

```
    InitializeComponent();
     var navigationPage = Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage;
     navigationPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#99CC07");
```

But then the statusbar doesn't update it's color:
[image: Green Navigation Bar, Blue Status Bar]

How can I make it so that the statusbar has the same (shade of) color as the navigationbar?
On iOS it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify both colors in the Android project. Go to Resources > values > `styles.xml` and edit the following values:

```
<!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
<item name="colorPrimary">#0066A1</item>
<!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#0E4369</item>
```